# Interpreting zero odds ratio from Fisher's exact test

Tags: r, odds-ratio, fishers-exact-test

I did fisher's exact test and I got an odds ratio equal to zero. Can you please clarify what it means? I want to plot the odds ratio but don't know how to deal with the zero and INF values.
below are the data and the test:

```
z <- matrix(c(69,13,33,0),nrow=2)
f <- fisher.test(z)
f
```

This is the output:

```
    Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  z
p-value = 0.01845
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.000000 0.742875
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
         0
```

Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If in a 2-by-2 table, we let $n_{11}$ be the counts in (1,1) cell, $n_{12}$ the counts in the (1,2) cell, $n_{21}$ those of cell (2,1) cell and $n_{22}$ those of cell (2,2), then the sample [odds ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds_ratio) is defined by

$$
\hat\theta = \frac{n_{11}n_{22}}{n_{12}n_{21}}.
$$

If any of $n_{ij}$ is zero, then $\hat\theta$ equals 0 or $\infty$ (it is undefined if both entries in a row or in a column are zero). Because these outcomes have positive probability, then the expected value and variance of $\hat\theta$ are not defined. A better well-behaved estimator is
$$
\tilde\theta = \frac{(n_{11}+0.5)(n_{22}+0.5)}{(n_{12}+0.5)(n_{21}+0.5)}
$$

Both $\hat\theta$ and $\tilde\theta$ have the same asymptotic normal distribution around the true odds-ratio $\theta$. Unless the sample size is quite large, however, the distributions of both $\tilde\theta$ and $\hat\theta$ are highly skewed. The log transform, having an additive rather than multiplicative structure, converges more rapidly to normality. An estimated standard error for $\log\hat\theta$ is

$$
\hat{\rm{se}}(\log\hat\theta) = \left(\frac{1}{n_{11}}+\frac{1}{n_{12}}+\frac{1}{n_{21}}+\frac{1}{n_{22}}\right)^{1/2},
$$

and thus by the large sample normality of $\log\hat\theta$

$$
\log\hat\theta \pm z_{\alpha/2}\hat{\rm{se}}(\log\hat\theta).
$$
provides an approximate confidence interval for $\log\hat\theta$. The confidence interval for $\hat\theta$ can be obtained by exponentiating the limits of the above intervals. A similar interval can be obtained using $\tilde\theta$ in place of $\hat\theta$.

However, when $\hat\theta = 0$ or $\hat\theta = \infty$, this interval cannot be applied. When $\hat\theta = 0$, one should take 0 as the lower limit and when $\hat\theta = \infty$ one should take $\infty$ as the upper limit. For the other bound you can use the above formula following some adjustment, such as replacing $n_{ij}$ by $n_{ij}+0.5$ in the estimator and standard error. Other methods are also possible, such as methods based on score function or conditional maximum likelihood estimation.

As for the odd-ratio estimate provided by `fisher.test`, the help page (`?fisher.test`) says

> **estimate**   an estimate of the odds ratio. Note that the conditional
> Maximum Likelihood Estimate (MLE) rather than the unconditional MLE
> (the sample odds ratio) is used. Only present in the 2 x 2 case.

This means that the odd-ratio provided by `fisher.test` is derived through an alternative estimator (here conditional maximum likelihood, which is a kind of maximum likelihood estimator) which need not coincide with the sample odds ratio $\hat\theta$ or $\tilde\theta$.

Here is a simple example that supports this claim.

```
fisher.test(matrix(c(69,13,33,23), ncol=2))

    Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  matrix(c(69, 13, 33, 23), ncol = 2)
p-value = 0.001425
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 1.556881 8.947718
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
   3.66139 

# sample odds-ratio estimate
> 69*23/(13*33)
[1] 3.699301
```

As you can see, the two estimates are not exactly the same although they are pretty close.

If you want to dive deeper into this subject I suggest having a look at Agresti's *Categorical Data Analysis* book.

Comment: Is there any way to correct for those odd ratios with zero? like adding 1 to all of the cells ? is this correct way to solve this problem?

Comment: @MarwahAl-kaabi , look up the Haldane-Anscombe correction for odds ratio, which adds 0.5 to each cell when there are 0 or low counts. There are other methods as well.